# A No - Sensa IQ Question?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, lateral-thinking

“This is a Non-sensa IQ Test Question,” said Grandpa giggling.

“It is not math but there may be some science behind it.

If

> X is 527 and
>
> I is 810 Then,
>
> IX is?
>
> A: 2810
> B: 75310
> C: 110
> D: A or B

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer Grandpa wants to hear is:

> **D: A or B**

Because:

> For a given Roman numeral, we need to:
>
>  1. Spell that number out in English,
>  2. Find elements in the Periodic Table whose symbols can be combined to spell the same word,
>  3. Give as our answer a number made up of those elements' atomic numbers concatenated together.

For example:

> X is 10 (TEN) in Roman numerals.
>  TEN = Tellurium (Te) + Nitrogen (N).
>  The atomic numbers of these elements are 52 and 7.
>  Hence **X=527**
>
>  I is 1 (ONE) in Roman numerals.
>  ONE = Oxygen (O) + Neon (Ne).
>  The atomic numbers of these elements are 8 and 10.
>  Hence **I=810**

So for IX:

> IX is 9 (NINE) in Roman numerals.
>  NINE = Nickel (Ni) + Neon (Ne).
>  The atomic numbers of these elements are 28 and 10.
>  Hence **IX=2810**
>
>  **BUT ALSO:**
>  NINE = Nitrogen (N) + Iodine (I) + Neon (Ne).
>  The atomic numbers of these elements are 7, 53 and 10.
>  Hence **IX=75310** as well!

Thus our answer is:

> **D** - since IX is equivalent to both 2810 and 75310 using his method!

Comment: One of these days @Stiv Grandpa will have a question that will take you at least few hours to answer!!

Comment: One of these days @DrD you'll discover that *I **am** Grandpa*... (PLOT TWIST)

Comment: Dang it. I should have known :)

Comment: A good lawyer might be able to argue that the answer is A, because there is no evidence to suggest a value can ever be made up of anything other than exactly 2 elements. (Just an observation, not trying to say you are wrong)